# ASCII graphic waveform generator

Tags: c++, strings, c++11, formatting, c++14

Working on some documentation lately, I had a need to convert a number of asynchronous serial waveforms into ASCII graphics characters.  Rather than draw them by hand, I decided to write a program to do it for me.  I'm interested in a code review, and particularly if there are smarter/shorter ways of coding the class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>

class waveform
{
public:
    waveform(std::string &s) : data_(s) {}
    std::vector<bool> to_bits() const
    {
        std::vector<bool> bits;
        bits.reserve(data_.size() * 10);
        for (auto &ch : data_) {
            bits.push_back(0); // start bit
            for (int mask=1u; mask != 0x100; mask <<= 1) {
                bits.push_back(ch & mask);
            }
            bits.push_back(1); // stop bit
        }
        return bits;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const waveform& w) {
        auto bits = w.to_bits();
        bool last = 1;
        for (const auto &b : bits) {
            out << (b ? "+---" : (last ? "+   " : "    "));
            last = b;
        }
        out << '\n';
        last = 1;
        for (const auto &b : bits) {
            out << (b != last ? "|   " : "    ");
            last = b;
        }
        out << '\n';
        last = 1;
        for (const auto &b : bits) {
            out << (b ? (last ? "    " : "+   ") : "+---");
            last = b;
        }
        out << '\n';
        int special = 0x201;
        for (const auto &b : bits) {
            if (special & 1) {
                out << (b ? "  P " : "  S ");
            } else {
                out << (b ? "  1 " : "  0 ");
            }
            special >>= 1;
            if (special == 0)
                special = 0x201;
        }
        out << '\n';
        return out;
    }
private:
    std::string data_;
};
```

### Sample driver

```
int main()
{
    std::string msg{"ST"};
    std::cout << waveform(msg) << std::endl;
}
```

### Sample output

```
+   +---+---+       +---+   +---+   +---+           +---+   +---+   +---+   +---
|   |       |       |   |   |   |   |   |           |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
+---+       +---+---+   +---+   +---+   +---+---+---+   +---+   +---+   +---+   
  S   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   P   S   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   P
```

Note that in this diagram, `S` stands for a start bit, `P` stands for a stop bit and the 8 data bits are sent least significant bit first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OOP design doesn't seem to be doing much for you.  It feels like you could get basically the same effect using just a function.  On the other hand, the `operator<<` method is basically a state machine, and it looks somewhat nastier than it needs to be.  There is copy-and-paste code, with bits of ASCII art all over the place, and a mini-Turing machine using the magic number `0x201`.

Assuming that the `to_bits()` helper function isn't important to you (I assume it isn't that important, because you wrote `#include <bitset>` then changed your mind), you could do better by defining a filtering output stream.  Here's my attempt to implement such a thing:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>

class waveform_ostream : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    explicit waveform_ostream(std::ostream &sink) : sink(sink) {}

protected:
    // Accept a byte of data
    virtual std::streambuf::int_type overflow(std::streambuf::int_type c) {
        output_bit(0, 'S');             // Start bit
        for (int i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; ++i) {
            output_bit((c >> i) & 1);   // Data bits, LSB first
        }
        output_bit(1, 'P');             // Stop bit
        return c;
    }

    // Flush
    int sync() {
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; ++row) {
            std::string s = lines[row]->str();
            sink << s << '\n';
            lines[row]->str("");
        }
        sink << std::flush;
        return 0;   // success
    }

private:
    bool state = 1;
    std::ostream &sink;
    std::stringstream level[2], risefall, captions;
    std::stringstream *const lines[4] = {
        &level[1],
        &risefall,
        &level[0],
        &captions
    };

    void output_bit(bool b, char caption='\0') {
        level[!b] << ((b == state) ? "    " : "+   ");
        risefall  << ((b == state) ? "    " : "|   ");
        level[ b] <<                          "+---";
        captions  << "  " << (char)(caption ? caption : b ? '1' : '0') << ' ';
        state = b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    waveform_ostream wout(std::cout);
    std::ostream out(&wout);
    out << std::string("ST") << std::flush;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't much like the original so I changed a number of things and produced this new version.  It allows for variable numbers of data bits and stop bits and is much better structured.  Each line is generated separately, and the images are selected using a two-bit lookup table.

### Waveform.h

```
#ifndef WAVEFORM_H
#define WAVEFORM_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace WAVE {
class Waveform
{
public:
    Waveform(std::string &s, int bits=8, int stopbits=1);
    std::size_t bits_per_char() const { return 1 + bits_ + stop_; }
    std::vector<bool> to_bits() const;
    void graphics_line(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<bool>& bits, int linenum) const;
    void bitlabel_line(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<bool>& bits) const;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Waveform& w) {
        auto bits = w.to_bits();
        for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i)
            w.graphics_line(out, bits, i);
        w.bitlabel_line(out, bits);
        for (const auto &ch: w.data_) {
            out 
                << std::setw(2*w.bits_per_char()) << "0x" << std::hex 
                << static_cast<unsigned>(ch & 0xff)
                << std::setw(2*w.bits_per_char()-2) << ' ';
        }
        return out;
    }
private:
    std::string data_;
    int bits_;
    int stop_;
};
}
#endif //WAVEFORM_H
```

### Waveform.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Waveform.h"

namespace WAVE {
Waveform::Waveform(std::string &s, int bits, int stopbits) 
    : data_(s), bits_(bits), stop_(stopbits) 
{
}

std::vector<bool> Waveform::to_bits() const
{
    std::vector<bool> bits;
    bits.reserve(data_.size() * bits_per_char());
    for (auto &ch : data_) {
        bits.push_back(0); // start bit
        for (int i=bits_, c=ch; i; --i) {
            bits.push_back(c & 1);
            c >>= 1;
        }
        for (int i=stop_; i; --i) {
            bits.push_back(1); // stop bit
        }
    }
    return bits;
}

void Waveform::graphics_line(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<bool>& bits, int linenum) const 
{
    static const char* graphic[3][4]{
        // 00      01      10      11
        {"    ", "+---", "+   ", "+---"}, 
        {"    ", "|   ", "|   ", "    "},
        {"+---", "+   ", "+---", "    "}
    };
    int last = 2;   // assume previous bit was 1
    for (const auto &b : bits) {
        last |= b;
        out << graphic[linenum][last];
        last = (last << 1) & 0x3;
    }
    out << '\n';
}

void Waveform::bitlabel_line(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<bool>& bits) const 
{
    enum states { START, DATA, STOP } state = START;
    int bitcount = bits_;
    for (unsigned i=0; i < bits.size(); ++i) {
        switch (state) {
            case START:
                out << (bits[i] ? " SE " : "  S ");
                state = DATA;
                break;
            case DATA:
                out << (bits[i] ? "  1 " : "  0 ");
                if (--bitcount == 0) {
                    bitcount = stop_;
                    state = STOP;
                }
                break;
            case STOP:
                out << (bits[i] ? "  P " : " EP ");
                if (--bitcount == 0) {
                    bitcount = bits_;
                    state = START;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    out << '\n';
}
}
```

### test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Waveform.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string msg{"ST"};
    WAVE::Waveform wave = WAVE::Waveform(msg);
    WAVE::Waveform wave2{wave};
    cout << wave << endl;
    cout << WAVE::Waveform(msg,7,1) << endl;
    cout << WAVE::Waveform(msg,7,2) << endl;
    auto bits = wave2.to_bits();
    for (bool b : bits)
        cout << b;
    cout << endl;
}
```

### output

```
+   +---+---+       +---+   +---+   +---+           +---+   +---+   +---+   +---
|   |       |       |   |   |   |   |   |           |   |   |   |   |   |   |   
+---+       +---+---+   +---+   +---+   +---+---+---+   +---+   +---+   +---+   
  S   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   P   S   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   P 
                  0x53                                      0x54                    
+   +---+---+       +---+   +---+---+           +---+   +---+   +---+---
|   |       |       |   |   |       |           |   |   |   |   |       
+---+       +---+---+   +---+       +---+---+---+   +---+   +---+       
  S   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   P   S   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   P 
                0x53                                  0x54                  
+   +---+---+       +---+   +---+---+---+           +---+   +---+   +---+---+---
|   |       |       |   |   |           |           |   |   |   |   |           
+---+       +---+---+   +---+           +---+---+---+   +---+   +---+           
  S   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   P   P   S   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   P   P 
                  0x53                                      0x54                    
01100101010001010101
```